How to Offload Main Thread Load Using Isolates in desktop_multi_window to Avoid UI Lag in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter desktop app using the desktop_multi_window package to open multiple windows, each running separate tasks. However, I’m experiencing UI lag, likely due to heavy processing on the main thread. I want each new window to offload tasks to separate isolates to prevent this lag.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Printing Thread HashCodes: I used print(Isolate.current.hashCode) in each window, and each window does seem to have a different thread or isolate hashcode.
Running Tasks in Background: I set up dummy tasks in each window, which confirmed they’re on separate threads, but the lag persists when the windows are open simultaneously.
My Questions:
1: How can I ensure each window’s intensive tasks fully utilize separate isolates without affecting the main UI thread?
2: Is there a way to limit communication between isolates to avoid bottlenecks?
3: Are there any recommended patterns for isolating and handling background tasks specifically for desktop_multi_window?
package I am modifying rn
https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window
